# How to find the inverse of $x^3+2x+6$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

If one were to take the cubic

$f(x) = x^3+2x+6$

How would one find the inverse of this function?

Comment: Finding the inverse of this function is equivalent to finding the roots of a cubic equation. Do you know how to solve cubic equations?

Comment: @Raskolnikov By factoring yes, otherwise no. Is there a general formula as for the quadratic equations?

Comment: Not the prettiest of formulas but: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cardano_formula

Comment: The answer would be huge. See [the general formula for cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we follow the method described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) with $a=1$, $b=0$, $c=2$, $d=6-y$
$$\Delta=-32 - 27 (6 - y)^2 <0 \qquad \forall y$$  Then the equation has one real root and two non-real complex conjugate roots. We also have $p=2$; so using the hyperbolic solution for one real root,we get (notice that $b=0\implies x=t_0$)
$$\color{blue}{x=-2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}
   \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} (6-y)\right)\right)}$$

In my opinion at least, this is nicer than the ugly
$$x=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^2-324 y+1004}+9 y-54}}{\sqrt[3]{2}\,
   3^{2/3}}-\frac{2 \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^2-324
   y+1004}+9 y-54}}$$ given by Wolfram Alpha.

**Edit**

Making the problem more general, considering the equation
$$x^3+\alpha x+\beta=y$$ we should have 
$$\Delta=-4 \alpha ^3-27 (\beta -y)^2 <0 \qquad \forall y \qquad \color{red}{\text{if}\qquad \alpha \geq 0}$$  and the solution would be
$$\color{blue}{x=-2\sqrt{\frac  \alpha 3} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{2\alpha}\sqrt{\frac 3 \alpha}  (\beta -y)\right)\right)}$$ nicer that
$$x=\frac{\sqrt[3]{-27 \beta +\sqrt{108 \alpha ^3+(27 y-27 \beta )^2}+27 y}}{3
   \sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \alpha }{\sqrt[3]{-27 \beta +\sqrt{108 \alpha
   ^3+(27 y-27 \beta )^2}+27 y}}$$

Comment: How is there $\sinh((1/3)\sin^{-1}...)$? I thought it would be $\sinh((1/3)\sinh^{-1}...)$.  Please check.  Thanks!

Comment: @OscarLanzi. This is easy : **typo** ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Write the equation in the form

$$x^3+2x+6=y$$ and set

$$x:=u-\frac2{3u}.$$

Then

$$0=x^3+2x+6-y=u^3-2u+\frac4{3u}-\frac8{27u^3}+2u-\frac4{3u}+6-y=u^3-\frac8{27u^3}+6-y.$$

This can be written as a quadratic equation in $u^3$,

$$(u^3)^2+(6-y)u^3-\frac8{27}=0$$ with the solutions

$$u^3=\frac{y-6\pm\sqrt{(y-6)^2+\frac{32}{27}}}2.$$

From this,

$$x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{y-6+\sqrt{(y-6)^2+\frac{32}{27}}}2}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{y-6-\sqrt{(y-6)^2+\frac{32}{27}}}2}.$$

---

Note that there was a shortcut to obtain the final result. By Vieta, the product of the quadratic roots is $-\frac8{27}$ so that $-\frac2{3u}$ is the cubic root of the other root.

Answer (score 0):

If
$$
y = f(x) = x^3 + 2x + 6
$$
you want to calculate
$$
x = f^{-1}(y)
$$
for a given $y$ from the image of $f$.

You can try to do this algebraically, going for a root of
$$
g(x) = f(x) - y
$$
which is a third degree polynomial as well, where [algebraic formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano%27s_method) exist, but they are more complicated than the common known degree two equivalents.

E.g. [see WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%5E3%20%2B%202x%20%2B%206%20-%20y%20%3D%200%20for%20x) for this case.

Otherwise you would need to apply numerical methods, e.g. [Newton iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method).